# Bash Script not executing on system reboot (Linux) Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a following script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/bin/warpper/
source venv/bin/activate
screen -A -m -d -S screen_celery celery -A tasks.celery worker --loglevel=info -c1 
screen -A -m -d -S screen_app ./app.py
```

I tried adding to crontab with @reboot command, but I get error

```
(CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
```

I tried adding it to .bachrc , adding script to /etc/init.d and then running command

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/nameofscript.sh defaults
```

Also added to rc.local

And I also created the shell script like this

```
( cd /var/www/html/bin/warpper/ && source venv/bin/activate && screen -A -m -d -S screen_celery celery -A tasks.celery worker --loglevel=info -c1 && screen -A -m -d -S screen_app ./app.py )
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what research have you done? ... your question has been asked many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much searching I figured that I had to add this after #!/bin/bash

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-service-name
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO
```

Got it working now. Thanks

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.